# How to start android activity from sencha script?

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch

Dear All,I want to merge existing android project  with sencha + phonegap. But i am still confused to start my existing activity from phonegap / sencha script. any suggestion would be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke Java methods from a WebView by [`addJavascriptInterface`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29), and here is an [example](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/trunk/Samples/WebViewDemo/src/com/google/android/webviewdemo/WebViewDemo.java) of how to use this method. Allowing Javascript to invoke your own Java methods makes it possible to start existing activity from phonegap / sencha script.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might be in need of WebIntents.  Check out [this article](http://smus.com/android-phonegap-plugins/) for some examples on how to call other activities.